# Stack rstan::stan_dens() posterior densities on one figure without facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstan

I'm trying to recreate this figure the top left panel of this figure:
[image]

In short I want to stack multiple posterior densities of a random effect on top of each other. I've looked at `rstan::stan_dens()` but it doesn't have any sort of `add = TRUE` argument. Is there a way to stack these posteriors quickly with a `rstan` plot function? Or should I just `extract()` the samples and plot it in ggplot the long way?

Some sample code I was playing with. Would be cool to stack the `theta`s.

```
library(rstan)
library(ggplot2)
example("read_stan_csv")
fit <- stan_demo("eight_schools") #select option 2 to temp load - takes some time

p <- stan_dens(fit, fill = NA, pars = "theta") + #can I stack these thetas easily?
      ggtitle("stack me please!")
p
```

plots this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what `rstan` does and use the unexported function `.make_plot_data`, passing the result straight to ggplot. Here, I'll use the `read_stan_csv` example, but you should be able to get your own example working if you change `pars` to "theta"

```r
library(rstan)
library(ggplot2)

example("read_stan_csv")

ggplot(rstan:::.make_plot_data(fit, pars = "z", TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)$samp,
       aes(value, group = parameter)) +
  geom_density() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: You're a wizard! Thank you! At first it wasn't working for me then I realized I needed to add a 3rd `:` Thanks again. You saved my feeble brain from more headache.